# Why is the google server returning error 401 when trying to get token?

Tags: c#, token, google-reader, http-status-code-401

i'm currently trying to develop an api for google reader and when i'm trying to get the token, the following error is being generated:

```
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
```

first i'm getting the session... and this works perfectly. then the following method i being called to get the token:

```
public String setToken()
{
    HttpWebResponse response;
    HttpWebRequest request;
    cookie = new Cookie("SID", this.sessionID, "/", ".google.com");
    String url = "http://www.google.com/reader/api/0/token";

    request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.Method = "GET";
    request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    request.CookieContainer.Add(this.cookie);

    response= (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        StreamReader r = new StreamReader(stream);
        this.token = r.ReadToEnd();
    }
    return this.token;
}
```

the exception is being generated in this line:

```
response= (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

**does anyone know what might be causing this error please?**

PS. I read the question : [Why am I getting a 401 (Unauthorized) error when POSTing to Google Reader API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275493/why-am-i-getting-a-401-unauthorized-error-when-posting-to-google-reader-api) however he was getting this error when he tried to post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google has changed, according to Eric Mann:

"As it turns out, Google has changed the authentication portion of the Reader API. Now, instead of passing the SID in a cookie when you make a request, you set an authentication header with the “Auth” key originally passed with the SID."

[Source](http://mindsharestrategy.com/2010/google-reader-api-a-brief-tutorial/#comment-144)